# Would a private adoption in Minnesota's Swedish community in 1880 been handled by the Lutheran Church?

Tags: adoption, church-records, minnesota

My mother's mother, first name Anna, was born in Minnesota (probably Frontenac) in 1879, and privately adopted by Solomon Long and Anna Lindberg, who lived in Princeton, Minnesota. Anna wasn't listed with them in the 1880 census, but was in the Minnesota 1885 census, so the adoption took place some time in those years. The adoption was private, and Anna was never told who her birth parents were. I've had researchers from the Minnesota Historical Soc. search the local county records but they could find nothing.

Does anyone know if the Lutheran Church got involved in such adoptions?

Are there records buried away somewhere?

The Long and Lindberg families were Swedish-Americans, and family tradition is that Anna's parents were Swedish as well. There's a sub-text to this story which I won't go into here, but I would like to find out if there are any records I can search before I go the DNA testing route.

Comment: I doubt the Church was officially involved, although one or two pastors may have been the go-betweens. Do you have your mother's baptism or confirmation records? The Lutheran Church practises infant baptism: if she baptized before adoption, that congregation may have been her birth family's. If after adoption, then her birth famly may have been non-Lutheran.